# Consulta sobre uso de picturebox en C#

Tags: c#

soy en el mundo de la programación, deseo saber como puedo utilizar un picturebox como botón para llamar un formulario.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bastará con que en el diseñador (o donde quieras que se le asigne el evento al picturebox) le añadas la asignación:

```
this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
```

Y luego crees tu función en el Form.cs

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Todos los pasos anteriores se hacen de forma automática desde VisualStudio haciendo doble click en el picturebox al que le quieres asignar el evento, o accediendo a las propiedades del pictureBox, clickando en Eventos (el icono de un relampago) y haciendo click en Action->Click
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Fran
Debo estar realizando algo de forma incorrecta porque me presenta error.

Comment: ¿Qué error te muestra?